# Angular warning: swal is deprecated

Tags: angular, typescript, deprecation-warning

I get the following message on building my project (Angular 9.0.5, sweetalert2 : 7.22.2):

> swal is deprecated: swal() overload for legacy alerts that use { useRejections: true }.

and it points to the following line, and other instance of similar code

```
  private promptFormError(title: string, errorMessage: string) {
    this.companyHelperService.errorPopup(title, errorMessage)
      .catch(swal.noop);
  }
```

I do understand that the issue is coming form the `swal.noop` part.
I tried looking into the doc linked to swal through IntelliJ, but I did not find anything specific related to this matter.

Can anybody please point me to a documentation, or explain to me how I am supposed to refactor this properly?

P.S: Is this a "real warning"? I would like to fix and stop ignoring it anyway

Comment: [https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v7.0.0](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v7.0.0). See Breaking change #1. As for the "real warning", the answer is yes, since `swal.noop` has been removed in v8. That means your code will break if you ever migrate to version 8.

Comment: Thanks, I think could write this comment as an answer, so I could accept it and close the question. I did not think about looking into the github, silly me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v7.0.0. See Breaking change #1.

As for the "real warning", the answer is yes, since `swal.noop` has been removed in v8. That means your code will break if you ever migrate to version 8.